# reverse look up based on foreign key queryset data

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Ok, I trust that the title may be confusing. As we go along I may update the question title in order to better reflect what it is referring to.

However. I have 3 models currently, `Zone`, `Boss` and `Difficulty`.  The models are linked via ForeignKey relationships like so:

```
class Difficulty(models.Model):
    '''Define the difficulties available in game'''
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.difficulty

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Difficulty Setting"
        verbose_name_plural = "Difficulties"


class Zone(models.Model):
    '''Stores the Zone information, referred to in-game as a Raid Instance'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    zone_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Boss(models.Model):
    '''Stores the information for each boss encounter within each zone'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    boss_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, null=True)
    difficulty = models.ForeignKey(Difficulty, null=True)
    guild_defeated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    appearance = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s [%s]' % (self.name, self.difficulty)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['difficulty', 'appearance']
        verbose_name = "Boss"
        verbose_name_plural = "Bosses"
```

What I am trying to achieve, Is filter each `Zone`, based on `Difficulty`.

For example

If Zone 1 has a `Boss` with 3 separate difficulties `[a, b, c]` I want to be able to get the data so that I can separately show in the template Zone 1 (Difficulty A), Zone 1 (Difficulty B) and Zone 1 (Difficulty C) and list each of the zones' bosses accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit easier if you add a `ManyToManyField` to `Zone` (or `Difficulty`):

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    difficulties = models.ManyToManyField(Difficulty, through=Boss, related_name='zones')
```

Then, you can query for all the difficulties related to a single zone:

```
for difficulty in zone.difficulties.all():
    bosses = difficulty.boss_set.filter(zone=zone)
```

To help with performance, use `prefetch_related('difficulties')`. In Django 1.7 you can use the new [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to also prefetch the bosses:

```
# I think that's how the new `Prefetch` works, I haven't actually used it yet.
zone = Zone.objects.prefetch_related(
           Prefetch('difficulties'),
           Prefetch('difficulties__bosses', queryset=Boss.objects.filter(zone_id=zone_id),
       ).get(...)
```

Comment: All I'm getting back from that is AttributeError: Cannot find 'bosses' on Difficulty object, 'difficulties__bosses' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman Ah, I always get confused about the default attribute/lookup names for multi-valued relationships. I find it more convenient to specify a `related_name` as a habit than to learn about those quirky defaults. I'd advice you to do the same, but I guess Django just adds an `s` so it becomes `difficulties__bosss`, or it appends `_set` so it becomes `difficulties__boss_set`.

Comment: Not sure if it's me that's getting confused, I'm not getting the result that I was after using this method.

Comment: What are you getting and what are you expecting? You'd still have to process the data and pass it to the template, but the loop should iterate over all difficulties related to a zone, and each iteration should have the zone, the difficulty and all bosses related to that particular combination of zone and difficulty.

Comment: well, when I iterate with `for difficulty in zone.difficulties.all():
    bosses = difficulty.boss_set.filter(zone=zone)` all I get is difficulty C, and none of the others.

Comment: @Neil What is the complete code of your view? Have you made sure there are bosses for that zone for the other difficulties?

Comment: There are bosses for all 3 difficulties that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: NameError: name 'zone' is not defined when trying to run that prefetch_related queryset.

Comment: @Neil You're right. If you have the `zone_id` available, use it. Otherwise, use whatever lookup parameters you have that you use to get the right `Zone` object.